# how do i use everyauth for simple (single step) authentication?

Tags: node.js, oauth, express, everyauth

how do i use everyauth to perform a very simple oauth authentication with node.js if i have both the public and secret key?  unlike a multi-step facebook-type authentication, i just want to do use everyauth to make simple authenticated REST calls.

and is everyauth the right tool for the job?

Comment: have you had a look a the example here: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/example/server.js

Comment: which among those methods is appropriate for my case, where i already have both the public+private keys and just need to access an oauth-protected resource? (is is obvious? ;))  skelly's example looks like it would work but it not an express-centric approach.  i am new to node.js, but it seems like express is a good platform to be using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Mikeals "Request" : https://github.com/mikeal/request OAuth example.

If you already have the public and secret key, you could just use the last piece in his OAuth example.

Comment: i see.  that looks pretty straight forward.  in that case, the oauth keys get applied to each outgoing request, correct?  this method cannot be used with express, can it?

Comment: Sure it can be used along with Express (you'd have a require('request')) in your Express app. I actually use it along with EveryAuth in an Express app now.